# JS floating point causing incorrect rounding

Tags: javascript, math

I have what may be an edge case scenario. When trying to round the value `4.015` to 2 decimal places, I always end up with `4.01` instead of the expected `4.02`. This happens consistently for all numbers with `.015` as the decimal portion.

I round using a fairly common method in JS:

```
val = Math.round(val * 100) / 100;
```

I think the problem starts when multiplying by 100. The floating point inaccuracy causes this value to be rounded down rather than up.

```
var a = 4.015,                // 4.015
    mult = a * 100,           // 401.49999999999994 (the issue)
    round = Math.round(mult), // 401
    result = round / 100;     // 4.01 (expected 4.02)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eVXRL/

This problem does not happen if I try to round `4.025`. The expected value of `4.03` does return; it's only an issue with `.015` (so far).

Is there a way to elegantly resolve this? There is of course the hack of just looking for `.015` and handling that case one-off, but that just seems wrong!

Comment: No, the problem happens as soon as you assign the value.

Comment: Make it a string, extract the decimals and manipulate those

Comment: @mplungjan Can you elaborate or provide an example? I think all that would do is push the same issue to the decimal portion since you still need to round there anyway.

Comment: `Math.round(Math.round(4.015*1000)/10)/100` does the job, but I don't know enough about floats to proof that it'll always work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) to do mathematical operations and that solved all my floating point issues.

The advantage of this lib was that there was no need to instantiate any sort of Big Decimal object (even though the lib does support BigDecimal). It was just as simple as replacing `Math` with `math` and passing the precision.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are not *real numbers*, they are floating point numbers.

There are infinite number of real numbers, but only finite number of bits to represent them, thus sometimes, there must be some rounding error if the exact number you want cannot be represented in the floating point system.

Thus, when dealing with floating point numbers, you must take into consideration, that you won't have the *exact* same number you had in mind.

If you need an exact number, you should use a library that gives you better precision, usually it will be using a [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), and/or symblic representation

More information can be found in the [wikipedia pag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)e, and in this (a bit complex, but important) article:  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thanks amit, I'm familiar with floating point numbers and their limitations, but that doesn't help with my issue. Do you have any recommendations for a JS library that gives better precision?

Comment: @anushr I gave some background for the problem and recommended using a library if accuracy is important. I am afraid I am not familiar with such library, as I am not really much a JS developer, but from short googling I got to this [bigdecimal.js](https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js) and [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/is-there-a-good-javascript-bigdecimal-library)

Comment: @anushr: It isn't precision that you need, but decimal representation (instead of binary). If 4.015 always becomes 4.0149999..., then it will never round to 4.02! If instead you have 4 DECIMAL places, then it will round correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to work with numbers as decimals, then use a decimal library, like [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js).

Floating point values in most languages (including javascript) are stored in a binary representation. Mostly, that does what you expect. In circumstances like this, your 4.015 is converted to a binary string, and happens to get encoded as the 4.014999999... value you saw, which is the closest binary representation available in a double precision (8-byte) IEEE754 value.

If you are doing financial math, or math for human consumption (i.e. as decimals), then you will want 4.015 to round to 4.02, and you need a decimal library.

There are plans to include decimal representation of floating point values in javascript (e.g. [here](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2008-February/005380.html)), since the new IEEE754-2008 standard includes decimal32 etc as decimal floating point value representations. For more read here: http://speleotrove.com/decimal/

Finally, if you are doing accounting maths in javascript (i.e. financial calculations which should not accidentally create or disappear money), then please do all calculations in whole cents/pence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp to extract and replace the digits to get what you want :

```
val = (val + "").replace(/^([0-9]+\.[0-9])([0-9])([0-9]).*$/, function(whole, head, lastdigit, followup) {
    if(followup >= 5) {
        return head + ("" + (parseInt(lastdigit) + 1));
    }else return head + lastdigit;
});
```

Otherwise you can use `val = val.toFixed(2)` but the value specific 4.015 gives 4.01 (4.0151 gives 4.02 as "expected").

Comment: I don't understand what this is doing. Care to elaborate please?

Comment: This code "casts" the number as a string (`val+""`) then using a regular expression gets some part of it and gives those to a function that will choose wether we need to round up or down